# change objects 'dynamically' in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a number of objects with a similar name format, e.g. `max_A`, `max_B`, `max_C` etc. Given the value of a certain object `ID`, I'd like to change the value of the object named `max_ID` (let's say increment by 1, assuming the object already stores an `int`).

E.g. if `ID = 'A'` then I'd like to execute `max_A += 1`, but if `ID = 'Q'` then I'd like `max_Q += 1`.

I know I can use [`eval('max_'+ID)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to get the value of `max_ID`, but how can I *change* the value?

Comment: Oh, wait, would [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the objects like bellow and use `endswith` function to find the appropriate object to be incremented:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


max_A = Data("max_A", 1)
max_B = Data("max_B", 2)
max_C = Data("max_C", 3)

obj_list = [max_A, max_B, max_C]


def increment_object_value(ending: str, objects: list):
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.name.endswith(ending):
            obj.value += 1


increment_object_value("A", obj_list)
increment_object_value("B", obj_list)
increment_object_value("C", obj_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think `exec()` would do it much simpler